# Read XML file which is referring another xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read XML from a file like:

```
var XmlData = XElement.Load(@"D:\test.xml");
```

`test.xml` refers to another xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE document [ <!ENTITY systems SYSTEM 'file:D:\systems.xml'> ]>
<Root>  
    &systems;
    <Servers>
         <Server>Server1</Server>
         <Server>Server2</Server>
    </Servers>
</Root>
```

Contents of `systems.xml`

```
<Systems>
  <System Id="1" Name="System1" />
  <System Id="2" Name="System2" />
</Systems>
```

However what I get back in `XmlData` is

```
<Root>  
    <Servers>
         <Server>Server1</Server>
         <Server>Server2</Server>
    </Servers>
</Root>
```

How can I include the contents of `systems.xml` while reading `test.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml", settings);

var XmlData = XElement.Load(reader);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So the trick was the DtdProcessing, I managed to get it done by passing the reader object to the Load method of XElement.